# Can I avoid loading the graphics

Tags: command-line, login, fglrx

I completely stuffed up when trying to purge the fglrx driver to upgrade it to the latest one.

This lab computer has full disk encryption, and there are 3 home accounts that are each encrypted.

When I load into the computer, I can enter the passphrase for the full disk encryption, however, the whole screen goes completely fuzzy before it gets to the login screen.

Is there some way I can turn off the graphics, So that people can access their files, copy them over to a backup disk, and maybe I can do a fresh install.

Alternatively, if I can get a command line going, I can attempt to resolve the problem. However, the computer goes fuzzy between entering the passphrase and login screen.

Please help

Comment: Can you not enter recovery mode (press shift right before loading Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 2):

Try hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and seeing if you can get to a tty right after entering the password.

Comment: Yep, got it, I'm in, thx

Comment: @Jackson: Instead of writing `thx`, please vote a helpful anwer up (^-sign, left to the post) and mark one of the helpful answers as `accepted answer` by clicking on the √-like symbol.